# Screen goes off during call and does not come back in Micromax A89

Tags: screen, proximity-sensor, micromax-a89

I am using Micromax A89 with

```
ICS 4.0.4
512 MB RAM
Screen 4.0 Inch
```

I am facing this problem since beginning. But it was solved automatically. Now again it happens when I dial a call or receive a call my mobile's screen goes off and does not come back. I must have to use power button to end the call (I set "Power button end call" checkbox from settings).

I think it's a proximity sensor problem but not sure?

But when I restart my mobile then it works for 1 or 2 calls but after it again it creates this issue.

Any help would heartily be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try wiping the proximity sensor area?

Comment: @sameer, yes I tried that too but no luck.

Comment: What about wiping cache and delvik cache? There is post in xda about it

Comment: You can also try this app if you are root
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.incredicontrol.ProxSensorCalibrator

Comment: @sameer, I didn't have root my device. But what about wiping cache and delvik cache? Without rooting, how can I do that? And will it hurt my device?

Comment: Try a factory reset that will clear the cache

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem but I found a simple and perfectly working solution:

1. Dial `*#*#7769#*#*` (Proximity sensor calibrator)
2. You will see 2 options `Start` and `Exit`
3. Click on `Start`.
4. Move your finger over the proximity sensor 3-4 times and try to change the value on screen.
5. If values are changing after 3-4 tries then your problem is solved.

Thanks to nighil g

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn whether or not it is caused by proximity sensor you can download [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tigermonster.proxfinder) and see if your proximity sensor is constantly sensing something that it shouldn't. If that is the case, I went through the very same problem and solved it. When I was searching the internet for a solution, someone simply suggested me to

> Take a little pipe and blow into the speaker of the phone strongly a
>   few times.

And it worked. I had to do it a few more times later on but it is solved permanently. Give it a try and I believe it'll work out.

Answer (score 0):

The question is too general and there aren't enough details to suggest a solution, it seems more likely to be a hardware problem.

Get your phone checked from a Micromax Service Centre.

PS : If you use a screen guard, it might be partially blocking the proximity sensor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: turn off the phone, then press volume up + volume down and power buttons for a while. It will show 2 options, recovery mode and factory mode. Select factory mode and there you do all tests and all your problems will be solved.

Comment: What do I have to do with those shown options? I cannot reset my mobile because I did it so many times in past and every time it will empty my mobile. So what options are there?

Answer (score -3):

You can try [Xposed Installer](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) app and can download [proximity disabler](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.mrchandler.disableprox) to disable your proximity sensor.. :-)

Comment: Could you link this?